# XMLHttpRequest() does not render view from my node.js/express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, xmlhttprequest

I am making a GET request to a route in my node/express app from the client side, maybe I am missing something very obvious but my app stays on path localhost:5000 and does not go to localhost:5000/adminPortal and render the view as per the express res.render() in the /adminPortal GET route.
I have been stuck on this for 3 days now and I'm sure it's very obvious... Perhaps an XML http request isn't the correct way? What would I need to use to pass a header (authorisation) to an express route for it to go to link and render the view?
Here is the client side code:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    console.log("Auth state changed");
    //console.log("verified: " + user.emailVerified);
    if(user){ 
        firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken().then(function(token){
            console.log('Sending request to with ID token in Authorization header.');
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

            req.open('GET', '/adminPortal', true);
            req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
            req.responseType = "document";
            req.send();


        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log("error:" + error);
        });

    }
```

Which goes to this route on my server side (After passing middleware):

```
router.get('/',isLoggedInAsUser, (req, res) => {
  let usersRef = db.collection('Users');
  var ownPolls = [];

  var allUsers = [];
  let firebaseUsers = usersRef.get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(user => {
      console.log(user.id, '=>', user.data());
      allUsers.push(user.data());

    });
    console.log("test");
    res.render('adminPortal/index', {allUsers: allUsers});
    return null;
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
  });  
});
```

Here is the middleware which checks the token in the header I pass in XMLHTTPrequest():

```
//Check if request is from User account
    isLoggedInAsUser: async function(req, res, next){
        if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
            console.log('Found "Authorization" header');
            // Read the ID Token from the Authorization header.
            idToken = req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1];
            try {
            const decodedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken);
            if(decodedToken){
                req.body.uid = decodedToken.uid;
                console.log("The decoded token: "+ decodedToken.uid);
                next();
                } else{
                    return res.status(401).send("You are not autheeeroized");
                }
            } catch (e){
                return res.status(401).send("You are not authroized" + e);
            }
          }
```

Comment: where are you handling the response from the XHR request?

Comment: I didn't realise I had to do this? I thought the page would be redirected automatically with the res.render()? How would this be possible with my XHR request? Thank you!

Comment: well ... the result of am XHR would never effect the current location - why would it?

Comment: I thought that the XHR request to my node/express server would somehow 'call' the res.render to be called automatically. Is there a way I can pass a header to a normal page link GET request from my node/express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click a link then the browser makes an HTTP request and loads the result as a new page.

If you submit a form then the browser makes an HTTP request and loads the result as a new page.

If you use an `<img>` then the browser makes an HTTP request and loads the result as an image in the place in the current document marked by the `<img>` element.

If you use `XMLHttpRequest` then the browser makes an HTTP request and returns the result to JavaScript where it will be stored in the XHR object:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/adminPortal', true);
xhr.addEventListener("load", function () { 
    alert(this.responseText); 
});
xhr.send();
```

The **whole point** of XHR is that it lets JavaScript communicate with the server via HTTP **without loading a new page**.

If you want to navigate to a new page, then use a link, or a form, or assign a new value to `location.href`.

If you want to use XHR then write JavaScript in the load handler to do something with the response.

Comment: Thank you very much for this response, I had a feeling I was not understanding very obvious. I wasn't aware there were different types of GET requests. So as you said I  would need an automatic redirect to the location /adminPortal, how would I send a custom header with this redirect GET request? Thanks again! Really hope I can put this issue to rest :)

Comment: You cannot set custom request headers for regular page load requests.

Comment: Ah ok, How would I then be able to send a token to my middleware in express when routing to /adminPortal (so that not everyone can access it)? So confusing!

Comment: Ok final question as I need to try solve it this week! Let's say I have a route /adminportal and I don't want anyone to just 'GET' it from my node/express server. How on earth would I protect it if I can't send a 'proof' of being logged in as admin to the node/express server?

Comment: The usual way to do that kind of authentication is to use a cookie.